# truncate dataset when variable falls below threshold

Tags: r

I wish to find the day on which variable hb falls below 90 for each record. I can find the day when x=min

```
f <- function(x) 1:length(x) <= which.min(x)
ind <- as.logical(ave(df$hb, df1$ id, FUN=f))
dfhb <- (df [ind, ])
maxday <- dfhb %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(daymax = last(day))
```

However, I can’t get hb<90

```
f2 <- function(x) 1:length(x) <= which(x<=90)
ind <- as.logical(ave(df$hb, df$id, FUN=f2))
dfhb <- (df [ind, ])
maxday <- dfhb %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(daymax = last(day))
summary(maxday$daymax)
```

I would be very grateful for your advice, bw Annemarie

```
id  day hb
1   1   95
1   2   NA
1   3   91
1   4   89
2   1   98
2   2   87
2   3   84
3   1   89
3   2   92
3   3   89
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: not sure but this? `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(daymax = toString(which(hb<90)))`

Comment: @Sotos That's almost perfect thanks. Now I get the daymax as a string - do you know how I can extract the first value of that? eg for patient 2 daymax=2, 3  How could I get it to just return the 2? Thanks

Comment: Then I 'd go with something like `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(daymax = which(hb<90)[1])`

Comment: @Sotos  - please go ahead and add your answer.   Deleting mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea for obtaining the first observed value that satisfies your threshold,

```
df %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 summarise(daymax = which(hb<90)[1]) 

# A tibble: 3 × 2
#     id daymax
#  <int>  <int>
#1     1      4
#2     2      2
#3     3      1
```